# Maven docs after codehaus terminated?

Tags: maven, plugins, documentation, mojo

Where can I get all the `org.codehaus.mojo` Maven plugins docs and sources once Codehaus.org was terminated?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at http://www.mojohaus.org which contains the complete state of documentation. Unfortunately at the moment not all documentations for all plugins have been migrated yet. This is currently under going.

If you miss a special plugin please create an issue on: https://github.com/mojohaus

Furthermore there you will find all the source code and you can create issues for the appropriate plugins there as well.

Comment: Will the group IDs for the plugins be changing too?

Comment: At moment they will not change. But i can't speak for the future...Which means only for future release all other versions are in Maven central which is immutable.

Comment: It looks like Codehaus's termination has caught a lot of people off guard...

Comment: The Codehaus termination was known for a long time.....since december laster year...

Answer (score 0):

You can view the most recent snapshot of the site before the Codehaus service was terminated by using the Wayback Machine.

Sunday, 6th of October 2014 seems to be the last capture. This link should take you to mirror of the site as it appeared on that day.

http://web.archive.org/web/20141006042640/http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/index.html

Of course, you could go to the new site located at:

http://www.mojohaus.org/

But if the page has not been rolled over to the new site, you can use the mirror in the mean time.